# aswSP.SYS BSOD if I start Process Monitor

Tags: windows-7, bsod, crash, avast, process-monitor

I'm trying to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) but I get a BSOD saying `aswSP.SYS` crashed.
`aswSP.SYS` is Avast! antivirus self protection system driver file.

Do you know why do I get this BSOD and more importantly how can I make [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) work without uninstalling avast antivirus?

Comment: I would choose another AV protection, Avast has many issues in Windows and there are better choices Free and Paid.

Comment: @Moab What AV protection would you recomend (free and paid)?

Comment: @Moab Why do you say "Avast has many issues in Windows"? Can you give me some more information?

Comment: you are having one of those issues right now, what more do you need to know.

Comment: Free, Microsoft Security Essentials, Paid, Eset